# Transform scale property CSS3 blurred in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to zoom a division when user hover , but it get blurred in chrome

here is my code:

```
.cost_block:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
transform: scale(1.01) translateY(-5px);
z-index: 1;
border-bottom: 0 none;}
```

I tried many time but still not getting right result.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't get totally rid of the blurred effect in Chrome.
But you can force the element to be drawn by the GPU by applying the following:

```
.cost_block {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Check out [this article](http://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/) for further information.

```
.cost_block {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0) translateZ(0);
}

.cost_block:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.01) translateY(-5px) translateZ(0);
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: This is a good workaround untill there will be a true fix to the blur in Chrome itself

Comment: Problem is with scale option

Comment: @aditi Just add it to the other properties: `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1) translateY(0);`

Comment: scale(1) will show default size. i want to zoom the box

Comment: Yes, but you need to apply that for the normal selector not for the hover state! See my updated answer...

Answer (score 0):

it's chrome's problem and we cant solve this by now. The only way to do is using integer in  attribute values and it may getting better

Comment: i am not \understanding integer attribute value

Answer (score 0):

You'd have more luck using the cross-browser prefix:

```
.cost_block:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            transform: scale(1.01) translateY(-5px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.01) translateY(-5px);
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
}
```