# CSS vertical align again (images with captions in boxes)

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I know vertical centering is a frequent topic, but all the solutions I found didn't work as desired with my example.

What I'm trying to do is have framed boxes of the same, fixed size next to each other, with images of variable size (unknown but within a known range), a text link caption below the image. I cannot use table styling because the number of boxes is also variable and I need them to wrap around to another row whenever they're getting to many to fit next to each other in the browser. The closest I got was with transform: translateY, but it still doesn't account for the text link's size, so it's below center, and it produces blurry text in Chrome and Firefox (tried several workarounds like perspective(1px) or translate3d(0,0,0), none worked for neither browser).

Any other methods that work for this concrete example?

This is the HTML (image sizes are only fixed for testing, they will be unknown in the real implementation):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boxes.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class=main>
   <div class=box>
    <div class=image>
     <p><img src="image1.png" alt=" " width=200 height=150></p>
     <p><a href="">Caption</a></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class=box>
    <div class=image>
     <p><img src="image2.png" alt=" " width=150 height=100></p>
     <p><a href="">Caption</a></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And this the CSS, prior to any fancy centering attempts:

```
div.main
{
width:996px;
border:0px;
padding:0px;
letter-spacing:0px;
argin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display:table;
}

div.box
{
border:1px solid grey;
width:220px;
height:220px;
text-align:center;
min-height:100%;
vertical-align:middle;
display:inline-block;
margin:5px;
}

div.box > div.image
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using `<p>` tags around your images? Try dispensing with those, and add a `<div>` around your captions with a `clear:both` style. Like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boxes.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class=main>
   <div class=box>
    <div class=image>
     <img src="image1.png" alt=" " width=200 height=150>
     <div class="caption"><p><a href="">Caption</a></p></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class=box>
    <div class=image>
     <img src="image2.png" alt=" " width=150 height=100>
     <div class="caption"><p><a href="">Caption</a></p></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And as such:

```
div.main
{
width:996px;
border:0px;
padding:0px;
letter-spacing:0px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display:table;
}

div.box
{
border:1px solid grey;
width:220px;
height:220px;
text-align:center;
min-height:100%;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
margin:5px;
}

div.box > div.image
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
display:block;
position:relative;
transform:translateY(-50%);
top:50%;
}
div.caption
{
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Oh, okay. I'm getting a proper view in Chrome now, but it seems that may be only because the calculation lands on a full pixel by chance now? If I zoom in, the text still gets messes up. It seems in Firefox the text itself is actually fine, but for some reason the underscore is terribly blurry...

Comment: @derboo I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033365/transform-scale-property-css3-blurred-in-google-chrome) addresses the same root problem. Unfortunately, there's no real fix-- it's a Chrome issue. The suggested hack is to force the GPU to draw it for you, by applying `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to your transformed styles.